# Javascript class inheritence

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I am trying to learn how to work with 'classes' in javascript.

Here is my code:

```
function Shape(x, y) {
    this.x= x;
    this.y= y;    
}

Shape.prototype.toString= function() {
        return 'Shape at '+this.x+', '+this.y;
    };

function Circle(x, y, r) {
    Shape.call(this, x, y); // invoke the base class's constructor function to take co-ords
    this.r= r;
}
Circle.prototype= $.extend(true, {}, Shape.prototype);

Circle.prototype.toString= function() {
    return 'Circular '+Shape.prototype.toString.call(this)+' with radius '+this.r;
}

var c = new Circle(1,2,3);
alert(c);
```

Is there a way to define the Shape's toString function inside it's constructor, or it does not make sense in this situation?

Comment: Does `this.toString = function() { ... }` not work in this case?

Comment: No it is not. See the difference:
http://jsfiddle.net/paptamas/qDSkj/ 
and
http://jsfiddle.net/paptamas/cbnLB/

Comment: Prototype is the correct way. It will create the toString function once. In the constructor, it gets created with each new.

Comment: John Resig has some pretty profound things to say about class inheritance, plus a great little script that solves many of the inheritance issues in js: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: One thing to note with extending this way: `new Shape().constructor === Shape`, but `new Circle().constructor !== Circle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on my understanding:

1. When you **move .toString() into the constructor** then .toString() becomes an **explicit member** of your instance. hence any call to .toString() will fire that explicit member.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/paptamas/qDSkj/

1. But when you define that as a prototype, (in the absence of an explicit member called .toString()), any call to .toString() method will fire .toString() function that is defined for the type of calling object (Circle in your case).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/paptamas/cbnLB/

In other words, explicit members have priority over prototype definitions and when you say

```
this.toString = function() ...
```

you are defining that function as a member of your instance (as oppose to member of your type - which is in a way not optimized as well).

Regards.